# Remote Desktop Connection without lock 1

Tags: remote

I am trying to find out the solution for remote desktop connection. If i access the remote PC through RDP connection, it is locking the remote PC. Customer requirement is, if the user connect the remote machine which is already logged in, the new user should see the desktop and there should an parallel operation at both the ends. Please let me know it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you describe cannot be done with the built-in client.

Comment: What version of windows is this? Windows Server edition has this functionality, but the regular versions do not.

Comment: Use teamviewer?

Comment: Windows 7 machine

Comment: Not available to do with windows RDP. What you are looking for is Damewear, Teamviewer, or another solution.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE: What I meant for 'parallel operation' means that if the remote user access the machine, the other user should be able to see what he/she is doing from remote and it is wise versa.

Comment: @AjayKumarV Thanks for clarify as parallel can be interpreted either way. In any case, yes then, the Team Viewer, VNC, and perhaps the other mentioned software packages would do this then for your need. Windows Terminal Servers have a Remote Control feature, and I believe Microsoft Lync client software has a remote screen sharing feature as well. I can speak to the Terminal Services Remote Control feature and I can speak to the Team Viewer software in this regard as ones that work real well. Depending on your needs, etc. you should test beforehand to confirm what works best for you.